# Which is better in android for showing dialog box on current application after completing some activity (Service or Notification)?

Tags: android

i have show progress bar with some limit.now after completing progress bar i want to show dialog message box. which must be came on current application..but i want that message box on any current current application....so which is better for it??whether to use service or notifications???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the Notification bar.

Just think, if they are in a different app and your giant dialog suddenly pops up in the middle of the screen. How annoying, your app get's uninstalled :-)

Notifications are the way to go, they inform the user that your service is done and can happily switch to your app when they are ready.

[Notification Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html)

[Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

Comment: yes ur rght..can you give me some sample of it....so that i can refer and dev.....

Comment: @Smith check out the 2nd link, it shows how to do any type of notification you want :-)